# CSS animation pop-in after pop-out in again conflicts with eachother

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I've got a peculiar problem which I didn't expect to see happen. [Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/asitis/pen/YVxPeq) for the situation. This is the case:

I have a hidden div that pops up on a button click, and pops 'in' after closing. This is handled with jQuery show/hide. For the UX I wanted to add a subtle pop-in animation via CSS. I added the following:

```
.popout { animation: popout .2s ease;}
.popin  { animation: popin .2s ease;}

@keyframes popout {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    90%  {transform:scale(1.1)}
    to   {transform:scale(1)}
}
@keyframes popin {
    from {transform:scale(1)}
    10%  {transform:scale(1.1)}
    to   {transform:scale(0)}
}
```

Now the animations work fine, but after closing the popup (adding the popin class) it reverts to the default css state, which is visible. So the result is you see the popup shrinking and then appear again to stay.
I can 'fix' this by adding `forwards` to the CSS animation call, but this forces the animation to keep going regardless of the other click. In other words; if I add `forwards` to the CSS animation, it stays hidden, but doesn't show up when you open it again (because the `forwards` is still active).

I again refer to [the Codepen](https://codepen.io/asitis/pen/YVxPeq) where you can see and try it yourselves. If you add `forwards` to the `.popin` class, it stays hidden after close, but cant open again.

So I'm wondering where my thought process went wrong; are we able to 'overwrite' or 'stop' a `forwards` setting? Am I missing something obvious? Or is this not the way to do it and should I look into jQuery animation instead?

Comment: try this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWrNPM

Comment: Oh wow, that simple huh. All you did was add that timeout? I thought of that before, but I thought it might give issues to having a fixed timeout to hide it, if the animation lags or changes in length.

Comment: you forget to hide the popup when click on close you have to add `$('popup').hide();`

Comment: you could use jquery fadeIn and fadeOut functions to this. Its more easier. eg: $( "popup" ).fadeIn( "slow" )

Comment: @AlexTimmer i think it wouldn't cause any problem

Comment: @Amal while your solution "works", it is brute force. You're not controlling the animation. You're just hiding the problem instead of fixing it. Nor are you explaining what's wrong with how it's currently handled. This means OP will not learn much, they won't be able to create more complex animations and handle them properly tomorrow. They will know how to hide them when they don't look right. :)

Comment: @Jibin.Jay I don't want a fade-animation, that's kinda the point.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu you are right mate..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as you add `popin`/`popout` classes, you're not removing the old one, thus ending up with both on the element, making it a lot harder (if not impossible) to control.

```js
$('.open').click(function() {
    //...
    $('popup').removeClass('popin').addClass('popout');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    //...
    $('popup').removeClass('popout').addClass('popin');
})
```

Also, you need to take into account that once animation ends, the element reverts to whatever `CSS` rules apply on it. So you need to add the `scale()` transforms to the class definitions if you want them to persist:

```css
.popout { 
    /* ... */
    transform: scale(1);
}
.popin  { 
    /* ... */
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Emvjaj

---

**Side note:** Instead of having two buttons replacing each other based on state, it is recommended you have only one button and handle the state changing inside the function you are calling. Some browsers/devices might trigger click on both buttons when doing the switch. It's safer with one button.

Comment: Just to clarify; I indeed forgot to remove the class onclick, but I do have that in the actual production environment. That alone doesn't fix the issue. Adding the scale to the classes does however :) It seems that's the one straw I missed. However it still doesn't work in my production enviroment yet, I'm betting this will eventually be the solution.

Comment: @AlexTimmer Is there any chance I could take a look at it? I might spot something you missed. Also, make sure you don't have any *cache* enabled. When in a rush to apply a fix, one can forget to disable/clear *cache* Happens to all of us. :)

Comment: yeah, I know, I've been working on this project for a few months now - I know how it can go ;) and thanks for the offer, but it won't be necessary; I'm pretty sure it has to do with the current warzone that is my jquery code spread over the whole system (Magento). I'll figure it out :)

And to clarify further; that codepen is just a 'demo' of the situation; the production site has completely different triggers and such.

Comment: @Alex, you're welcome. See the added side-note. I'm on a linux machine, on chrome and sometimes it triggers click on both buttons. Just make a `togglePopup()` function and use an `if` inside it.

Comment: @AlexTimmer Here's how I'd simplify it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmjVor

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your example in codepen, 
by simply removing the alternate classes and leaving the forward-fill property in place, your code seems to work just fine.

Comment: As stated above in the other comments I do remove the alternate classes in my actual production environment, and in that case simply adding forwards to both doesn't work as well. But good to hear that in the simple use case, this would work.